# Cannot retrieve filename and fileurl from realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the Firebase model class like this. I am trying to retrieve filename and fileurl under User Uid. if anyone needs more information please ask me.

```
public class model {
    public String filename;
    public String fileurl;

    public model() {
    }

    public model(String filename, String fileurl) {
        this.filename = filename;
        this.fileurl = fileurl;

    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }
    public String getFileurl() {
        return fileurl;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public void setFileurl(String fileurl) {
        this.fileurl = fileurl;
    }
```

I am using FirebaseUI's recycler view in my code. I want retrieve data under user UID please rectify my mistakes. i make a adapter for this.

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<model>()
                    .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users"),model.class)
                    .build();
    adapter=new myadapter(options);
    recview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is my  realtime DB structure. I will put fileurl later in my firebase database.

[image]

This is manifiest.xml file. anything wrong in manifiest.xml file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MySchool"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".ebooks"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".viewpdf"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ProfileView"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".OTPActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".PhoneAuthentication"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:exported="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "i will put fileurl later in my firebase database"? if you don't give it those fields, it wont get those fields. It's as simple as that. You need to add them in order to get the values in your app

Answer (score 1):

When passing those two arguments to the `setQuery()` method:

```
.setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users"),model.class)
```

It means that the adapter expects to render on the screen `model` class objects. If you take a closer look at your database schema, under the "Users" node, you can see a UID (`NseK...wbv2`), and right under it, two pushed IDs. So when reading the data from the database, the Firebase-UI library tries to map each child under the above reference into an object of type `model`, which is actually not possible since the immediate children are strings and not `model` objects. To solve this you have to add a call to `.child(uid)`. So in code, it should look like this:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = db.child("Users").child(uid);
//...
.setQuery(uidRef, model.class)
```

Comment: thanks a lot Alex Mamo. you teach me very well.

Comment: Alex Mamo i get error " Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type" after some tiime

Comment: If you have any other problems that derive from this one, then a new question should be added separately. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: i posted a new question regarding this problem

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

Comment: thanks Alex Mamo. i am getting diffrent error now. that was post a new question. if you understand that problem please help.

Comment: thanks Alex Mamo I changed my DB structure. This code is working very well now. thanks a lot again.